# Requesting Hidden-Service failed

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose, tor

**My problem**

I am trying to host a website via the tor-network in a docker-container.My problem is that I cannot access the onion-link via the tor-browser.

**The docker-file**

```
FROM node:latest

MAINTAINER stevan

WORKDIR /frontend/

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN npm install

RUN apt-get install tor -y

RUN echo "HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/" >> /etc/tor/torrc

RUN echo "HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:3000" >> /etc/tor/torrc

RUN service tor restart 

CMD cat /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname && npm start
```

**The docker-commands**

`docker build -t my-hidden-service .`

`docker run -p 3000:3000 my-hidden-service:latest`

**Explanation**

This docker-file starts an express-server and forwards the incoming connections on port 80 to my express-server port 3000. In the run command I map the container-port 3000 to my host-port 3000.

**Debugging**

I have tried to curl `http://localhost:3000` and it works perfectly fine but accessing the hidden service seems impossible. I can not come up with a solution. I tried the hosting locally on my raspberry pi via the hidden-service without docker and it works. Accessing the onion link was possible,so it seems that there is be a problem with the port forwarding in the docker file.

I am looking forward for your answers.

Cheers, Stevan!